# RegEx never matches in a form tag pattern

Tags: jquery, html, regex, forms, validation

Practicing making and using forms for a jQuery class. We were given the following as part of the assignment:

```
    Password must follow the pattern:
    - first character must be a letter
    - following characters may be letters, numbers, and an underscore
    - must be between 3 and 15 total characters
the password and the confirm password entries must match

You may use HTML5 input types and attributes. The following regular     
expression can be used for the password: /^[a-zA-Z]\w{3,14}$/
```

and so, within my page I put the password tag (inside the form tags) like so:

```
<input type="text" id="password" pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]\w{3,14}$/" required>
```

Yet no password that meets the listed criteria passes. Every time I hit submit it gives me a pop-up saying "Please match the format requested". Did I do something wrong? I've been reading up on the regex and it looks okay to me (granted regex has never been a strong point for me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove both the regex literal delimiters and the start and end marks in a `pattern` attribute:

```
<input type="text" id="password" pattern="[a-zA-Z]\w{2,14}" required>
```

(I also changed a `3` to a `2` because the total numbers of characters is supposed to be between 3 and 15)

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) :

> **pattern**
>
> A regular expression that the control's value is checked against. **The
>   pattern must match the entire value, not just some subset**. Use the
>   title attribute to describe the pattern to help the user. This
>   attribute applies when the value of the type attribute is text,
>   search, tel, url or email; otherwise it is ignored. The regular
>   expression language is the same as JavaScript's. **The pattern is not
>   surrounded by forward slashes**.

Comment: You are awesome! That fixed it instantly, thank you!